# Error "Introduction must be simple markdown..." when editing example

Tags: support

I'm editing an example of https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jsf/8164/comments-in-jsf and get the error message `Introduction must be simple markdown - no images, tables, lists, etc.` when I want to submit the change for review. Now, afaik I have to drop the changes into a text editor, cancel editing and adjust the introduction which doesn't have any non-simple markup at first sight.

That's no very intuitive and if editing examples depends on a correctly formed introduction the latter should be enforced before allowing edits to the examples.

[image]